# Display Terms of Service in Cognito Built-in Login UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there any way to have the user accept Terms of Service when creating a new account using the Cognito Built-In Login UI?

If not is there frontend code I can copy that is similar to the built-in UI?

Comment: Congnito do not have anything inbuilt for terms and conditions and built in login ui retrieve the attributes and generate form.